# How can I set value of `myListView` through XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I define my own control - `NameInfoControl`, which are based on `UserControl` thorough XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AcadLoadManager.NameInfoControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button x:Name="btnAdd" x:FieldModifier="public" ToolTip="Add record" >
                    <Image Source="/AcadLoadManager;component/Icons/bullet_sparkle.png" Width="16"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnEdit" x:FieldModifier="public" ToolTip="Edit record">
                    <Image Source="/AcadLoadManager;component/Icons/bullet_edit.png" Width="16"/>
                </Button>
                <Button  x:Name="btnRemove" x:FieldModifier="public" ToolTip="Remove record">
                    <Image Source="/AcadLoadManager;component/Icons/bullet_cross.png" Width="16"/>
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
            <ListView x:Name="myListView" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Global name" 
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GlobalName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Local name" 
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LocalName}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It looks so:

[image]

My control has `ListView` item, named as *myListView*. How can I set value for `ItemsSource` property of *myListView* through XAML for `NameInfoControl` instance? I need it in the next code:

```
<GroupBox Header="Command groups:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
    <local:NameInfoControl/>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML of your `NameInfoControl` bind the items of your `myListView` to the `DataContext` of your control:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myListView" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1">
```

And then in the parent XAML where you use that control bind the `DataContext` to the list that contain the items that should be displayed:

`<local:NameInfoControl DataContext="{Binding MyCollectionOfItems}" />`

Comment: But item source I must to get from `ListBox.SelectedItem.Items`, which are located on `MainWindow`. My `NameInfoControl` instance located on this window too, bot as nested in other control. I have tried such code: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstAcads, Path=SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HKLMApplications}"` but it ain't working for me.

Comment: Add a new property to your mainwindow that contain the SelectedItems and bind against that. It looks like you have reached a complexity where you should start considering using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Oh, problem solved. I set `DataContext` for owner, and `ItemsSource` for my element. Now works fine. Thanks all!